# Why are method-local static variables bound to class and not to instances?

Tags: c++, class, static, instance, language-design

In this class

```
struct A
{
    ...
    void method()
    {
        static x=0;
        x++;
        ...
    }
}
```

for each instance of A, a call to `method()` will increment `x` for all instances.

I expected `x` to be incremented for the instance in which `method()` is called only, and not to affect `x` for any other instance. This effectively binds the method-local static variable to the class, and as a side issue: why can I not have class-level static variables (only const's), which I would expect to behave as the method-local static variable does currently.

I know I can 'fix' this with some extra code, but still want to understand the reason for this behavior.

Some code for those who want to see the behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

inline void PRINTSTRING(const std::string &s) { std::cout << s; std::cout.flush(); }
template<typename...T> void say(T...t) { std::stringstream ss{}; (ss<<...<<t); PRINTSTRING(ss.str()); }
template<typename...T> std::string says(T...t) { std::stringstream ss{}; (ss<<...<<t); return ss.str(); }
template<typename...T> bool sayerr(T...t) { say("Error: ", t...); return false; }

struct A { std::string sa{"A"}; void who() { static int a=0; a++; say(says(sa, " a=", a, "\n")); }};

std::vector<A*> AList{};

void killas() { while (!AList.empty()) { auto it=AList.begin(); delete (*it); AList.erase(it); }}
A* newa(const std::string &s) { A *pA=new A; if (pA) { pA->sa=s; AList.push_back(pA); } return pA; }
void showas() { if (AList.empty()) say("-empty-\n"); else for (auto p:AList) p->who(); }

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    say("\ntesting if a static var in a method is bound to instance or to class ...\n\nexpect 'empty'\n");
    showas();
    newa("one"); newa("two"); newa("three"); newa("four"); newa("five");
    say("\nif bound to instance expect all 1's\n");
    showas();
    say("\nif bound to instance expect all 2's\n");
    showas();
    killas();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `static` means static storage: every execution of that function uses the same address for statically-allocated storage for `x`.  It's exactly like a global var, or file-scoped `static`, in terms of how it works in asm, it's just that the compiler only lets you access it from the scope where you declared it.

Comment: If a method definition could add more state (per-instance data) to an object, `sizeof(class T)` would need to see the *definition*, not just declaration, of every member function, forcing all class member functions to be defined in `.h` files.  Unless that possibility was restricted to member functions defined inside the class declaration?  But that would also be weird.  If you want a private member var, declare a member var.  And BTW, you *can* have class-scoped non-const `static` member vars, like `class foo { static int x; };`  You seemed to think you couldn't? https://godbolt.org/z/5kUfxG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) that, while not explaining the reason for the behavior, does give a good description of it's uses.

Also regarding [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) it says:

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static or
>   thread_local
>  (since C++11) have static or thread (since C++11)
>   storage duration but are
>  initialized the first time control
>   passes through their declaration (unless their
>  initialization is
>   zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before
>   the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is
>   skipped.

and a little further on:

> Function-local static objects in all definitions of the same inline
>   function
>   (which may be implicitly inline) all refer to the same
>   object defined in one
>   translation unit.

I was not aware of this and knowing it now will certainly help to prevent unintended 'features' in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Static member is belong to class not instance,method-local static various is also like this. You just need a normal class private member.